# How remove for loops in an empirical permutation test

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, permutation, correlation

The following script works well with small datasets but very slow for big datasets. How can I remove for loops and speed up the performance and how can I make sure which script slows down the performance.

```
Pvalue<-matrix(nrow = nrow(a), 
               ncol = nrow(b))
number_of_permutations = 1000
diff.random = NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(a))
for(j in 1:nrow(b)) {
    if(i>j)#selecting only lower part of the symmetric matrix
        next
    combined<-as.numeric(c(a[i,], b[j,]))
    for (k in 1 : number_of_permutations) {
        shuffled = sample(combined,
                          length(combined))
        diff.random[k] = cor(shuffled[1 : 6],
                             shuffled[7 : length(combined)],
                             method="spearman") 
    }
    Pvalue[i,j] = (sum(abs(diff.random) >= abs(rcorr.observed[i,j])) /
                   number_of_permutations)
    print(i)
}
```

**Sample files**:

```
a<-structure(c(7.284640193, 8.386102403, 10.27187091, 6.56612737, 
8.969982518, 10.03221978, 7.193522121, 7.358283395, 10.92117745, 
7.162802801, 8.297228578, 11.36980277, 7.865611714, 7.999185693, 
10.33028086, 6.831671275, 8.953536984, 8.826461297), .Dim = c(3L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("DDR1_MIR4640", "RFC2", "HSPA6"), c("a_1", "a_2", "a_3", "a_4", "a_5", "a_6")))

b<-structure(c(9.1048886, 6.4114527, 5.7281808, 9.4302985, 6.2576226, 
4.871274, 9.187927, 5.9036324, 4.3635891, 8.6896685, 6.6680496, 
5.5445622, 8.9274641, 6.4394849, 5.5175364, 7.8629553, 8.4304969, 
6.1402062), .Dim = c(3L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("FAM174B", "SV2B", 
"RBPMS2"), c("b_1", "b_2", "b_3", "b_4", "b_5", "b_6")))

rcorr.observed<- structure(c(0.00309597514569759, -0.0526315793395042, -0.108359135687351, 
NA, -0.0567595474421978, -0.0299277603626251, NA, NA, -0.116615064442158
), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
```

Comment: try using permutation function in gtools package to prepare a list of indices you have used  to call i and j. this removed first two loops for you. Also I thinks the last script which computes the pvalue have greater influence on performance.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing operations for each pair of rows (i,j) in matrixes `a` and `b`, so it's unavoidable that doubling the number of rows in `a` doubles the run time, as does doubling the rows of `b`.  However you can gain a little efficiency by storing less data and reducing the number of function calls (particularly calling `abs()` outside the `for` loops).

```
abs.rcorr.observed  <-  abs(rcorr.observed)
Pvalue<-matrix(nrow = nrow(a), 
               ncol = nrow(b))
number_of_permutations = 1000

stopifnot(is.numeric(a))#assureing a and b are numeric here means we 
stopifnot(is.numeric(b))#don't have to call 'as.numeric()' in the for loops

subset_a = 1:ncol(a) # the colon opporator is a function call so
subset_b = ncol(a) + 1:ncol(b) # setting variables outside the for loops can save some time 

len_combined =ncol(a) + ncol(b)

for(i in 1:nrow(a))
for(j in 1:nrow(b)) {
    if(i>j)#selecting only lower part of the symmetric matrix
        next
    combined<-c(a[i,], b[j,])# dont need to call as.numeric if a and b are alread numeric
    p = 0 # the number of times that the random (permutation) statistic meets or exceeds the observed statistic
    for (k in 1 : number_of_permutations) {
        shuffled = sample(combined,len_combined)
        if(abs.rcorr.observed[i,j] <= 
           abs(cor(shuffled[subset_a],
                    shuffled[subset_b],
                    method="spearman"))){
            p = p + 1
        }
    }
    Pvalue[i,j] = p / number_of_permutations
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: @Jthope, thank you very much. In the second if you count Ps but I need the summation of all amounts that are greater than calculated correlation. can you help more? bests

Comment: in your code `sum(abs(diff.random) >= abs(rcorr.observed[i,j])` is the number of random statistics whose absolute value exceeds that of the observed statistic.  This is also what `p` is because it is incremented in the `if` clause which is only true when the absolute value of the ransom statistic exceeds that of the observed statistic. [after typo fix from `>=` in the if clause to `<=` just now ]